# axios and fetch returning empty response data in React

Tags: reactjs, axios

My code for calling an api is:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
class Hello extends React.Component{
 constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
        data: "good"
    }
    this.setdata=this.setdata.bind(this);
 }
 setdata(){
    return axios.get("http://52.14.161.145/1").
    then(res=>{
        return res.json;
    });
 }
 componentDidMount(){
    this.setdata().then(res=>{console.log(res);this.setState({data: res})});
 }
render(){
    return (<div><p>{this.state.data}</p></div>);
  }
 }
export default Hello;
```

I also know about react methods lifecycle and asynchronous nature of axios and fetch api calls. I am able to see the response in network tab of chrome, but `setdata` always returns undefined.
Also note that I am bundeling the react code and serving it through express server.

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Why not just set the stae in the setData fucnction?

Comment: That is also not working. I have tried almost all possible ways but in vain

Comment: You should use **async** and **await**, here is an example hope it helps: https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-use-async-await-with-axios-in-react-e07daac2905f

Comment: It's res.data.json

Comment: I have already tried async and await. Thats why I posted question here

Comment: Check you console. You might have CORS issue.

Comment: One thing I want to ask is that would it work if I move the entire code inside componentDidMount

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can achieve in this way.
- Better to set your state in where your are getting response.
- This is not `fetch` call , in `axios` `res.json` is not required.
- You will get your data in `res.data`

  ```
   setdata(){
     axios.get("http://52.14.161.145/1").
      then(res=>{
        console.log(res.data);
        this.setState({data: res.data})
       });
     }

  componentDidMount(){
   this.setdata();
  }
  ```

Comment: in console(res.data) what you are getting ?

Comment: As I am new to this site, In case I have accepted an answer, can my question get downvote even then??

Comment: It depends on community members, what they think about your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be

```
const response = await fetch("http://52.14.161.145/1",{
 headers:{
  "Content-Type":"application/json"
 }
});
console.log(await response.json())
```

Comment: OP uses `axios`. It parses json

Comment: It says res.json is not a function

Comment: Actually the problem is that api is returning empty response when called with axios or fetch. But I can see the response in network tab

Comment: if you try this on the browser console it is printing the data on the console